# Bash cvs file to json new file

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

i m lie to use  bash to import data  from  cvs  to json  file
Example Cvs

```
"Product ID";"Product Name";"Price";"Description";
"1;"Example";"200";"Descripcion here...";
"2;"Example2";"300";"Some here...";
```

And i want  some like this:

```
{
"title":"Example",
"price":200,
"description": {
      "plain_text": "Some here..."
   },
"Predifined":static content,
"Another Predifined":static content,
}
```

Here is the script i try to use

How i can make this ? thx

Comment: where is the script you tried to use?

Comment: Sry i m very noob! =(  i tried one  but i m not a programer!

Comment: Make sure when posting questions that the expected output you post can be generated from the sample input you post so the [mcve] you provide clarifies your requirements and gives us real data we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 3):

After fixing your input so that it is properly semicolon-separated:

```
jq -R 'split(";")
| map(gsub("^\"|\"$";""))
| {title:.[1],
   price: .[2],
   description: { plain_text: .[3] }}' input.csv
```

yields:

```
{
  "title": "Product Name",
  "price": "Price",
  "description": {
    "plain_text": "Description"
  }
}
{
  "title": "Example",
  "price": "200",
  "description": {
    "plain_text": "Descripcion here..."
  }
}
{
  "title": "Example2",
  "price": "300",
  "description": {
    "plain_text": "Some here..."
  }
}
```

Comment: I run this in  console  and say error !!!
Why ?

root@mail:/var/www# jq -R  'split(";")| map(gsub("^\"|\"$";""))| {Product ID:.[1],  price: .[2], description: { plain_text: .[3], }}' id.csv
error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '}'
split(";")| map(gsub("^\"|\"$";""))| {Product ID:.[1],  price: .[2], description: { plain_text: .[3], }}                                              1 compile error

Comment: If you want to include a space in a key name, you will have to quote it: "Product ID"

Answer (score 1):

Well, that previous `jq` answer is more elegant.  I did this, using only bash...  Since I was done I put it here anyway, but I feel a bit silly after that nice answer from @peak.

To the OP, the first one is free.  For future questions, users here will **help** you, but you have to get started and face a particular issue you need help with ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash

csvfile='input.csv'

# Make sure the file exists
if [ ! -f $csvfile ]
then
    echo "ERROR: file $csvfile does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Read the input file line per line
while read line
do
    # Capture the information out of the line, fields separated by ;
    IFS=';' read pid pname price desc <<< $line

    # Output the JSON for this line
    echo '{'
    echo "    \"title\":$pname,"
    echo "    \"price\":$price,"
    echo "    \"description\": {"
    echo "        \"plain_text\":$desc"
    echo "    },"
    echo "    \"Predifined\":\"static content\","
    echo "    \"Another Predifined\":\"static content\""
    echo '}'

    # Just to split the line's output
    echo ""
done <$csvfile
```

Which produces this output:

```
{
    "title":"Product Name",
    "price":"Price",
    "description": {
        "plain_text":"Description"
    },
    "Predifined":"static content",
    "Another Predifined":"static content"
}

{
    "title":"Example",
    "price":"200",
    "description": {
        "plain_text":"Descripcion here..."
    },
    "Predifined":"static content",
    "Another Predifined":"static content"
}

{
    "title":"Example2",
    "price":"300",
    "description": {
        "plain_text":"Some here..."
    },
    "Predifined":"static content",
    "Another Predifined":"static content"
}
```

---

2nd version of the same script, this one will output each product section into it's own JSON file.  Note that I remove the first line of the CSV file since it is just headers and I do not want to create a file for the headers.

```
#!/bin/bash

csvfile='input.csv'

# Make sure the file exists
if [ ! -f $csvfile ]
then
    echo "ERROR: file $csvfile does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Read the input file line per line
sed '1d' $csvfile | while read line
do
    # Capture the information out of the line, fields separated by ;
    IFS=';' read pid pname price desc <<< $line

    # Strip the " from $pid and define the output filename
    output_filename="$(echo $pid | tr -d '"').json"

    # Output the JSON for this line
    echo '{'                                               >$output_filename
    echo "    \"title\":$pname,"                          >>$output_filename
    echo "    \"price\":$price,"                          >>$output_filename
    echo "    \"description\": {"                         >>$output_filename
    echo "        \"plain_text\":$desc"                   >>$output_filename
    echo "    },"                                         >>$output_filename
    echo "    \"Predifined\":\"static content\","         >>$output_filename
    echo "    \"Another Predifined\":\"static content\""  >>$output_filename
    echo '}'                                              >>$output_filename

    # Just to split the line output
    echo ""                                               >>$output_filename
done
```

Some might comment that using a here doc instead of doing multiple echo statements like this would be more efficient, but I find that here docs mess up the indentation, and I started from the original script, it was faster like this.

Comment: The jq  no work for me ! i dont know to use this.
You script  is working well  ,  can u  help me to create a file for each ID.
Example  
Product Id 1 > 1.cvs
Product Id 2 > 2.cvs
It is posible? Thx!

Comment: Sure, look at the answer, I added a second version of the script.

Comment: Nic3500 your scrip is GREAT, thx so muchhhhhhhhh.
Awesomeeeee! 
Bonus track  =)
Its posible to add  to this scrip  some like this 
[bash whit if](http://petshopanimall.com/input.txt)
I try but giveme error! why ?

Comment: No problem.  If you could accept the answer I would appreciate.  As for your "bash whit if" I do not understand, please add details.

Comment: Thx Nic3500    i like the improve the  file  this work  great , i like to add 3 more column  "price_combination"  ( example 20 , 300 or 500 $) and  another column " color" (example red , white , etc).
I want to make a condition if price is 0  the price is in  "price_conbination"  and have "color "  too.
can i add to the generation json  name + color  and price + combination_price? 
i attach the 1.csv   for more  information [link](http://petshopanimall.com/1.csv)

Comment: Maybe it is very dificult  is this is  for u  i understand! thx alot.
I realy like to  learn bash and syslinux for hoby , what u recommend  a book or something ? thx again

Comment: Good morning, no it is not difficult for someone who knows the language.  This site i a great resource http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.  Start with the guide, BashFAQ later.  If you want to add columns, the line that assigns values to variables is `IFS=';' read...`.  More columns == additional variables.  Then you can use an `if then else fi` conditional to verify if the price is `-eq` 0.  You have a good base here to get started.  If you get stuck research, worst case post here we will help.  You now must learn to walk on our own young Padawan :-)

Comment: Nic3500  How  r u today ?  I was  fighting whit the console about 3 hs jahahaha
i found  i need to put ' '  to the  If eq 0  =O.
The bash work very good but giveme some errors when i  executed ! should i worry ? Can u test this for me  and giveme  any clue ?  [bash file](http://petshopanimall.com/bash.txt)   and [csv file](http://petshopanimall.com/input.txt) Thx for the guide very helpful